# How far will the GC go

Tags: java, garbage-collection

How far will the Java GC go?  Lets say I have this code:

```
public class MyClass {
    private Object myObject = new Object();
    public void clear() {
        myObject = null;
    }
}

public class MyMain {
    ...
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    ...
    myClass.clear();
    myClass = null;
}
```

Do I need to call myClass.clear() before setting myClass to null to be sertain the GC will delete myObject inside myClass?  Or is it enough to set myClass to null and the GC will delete all nested objects?

Maybe I'm a bit paranoid and the answer is as easy as "The GC will eventually delete any objects that is not reachable by any running code or any future available code".  So if a created object is not available, or never will be available, in any running code, it will eventually be a victim of the GC even thought it is nested and makes a C++ programmer scared?

Comment: They're about the .NET garbage collector, not the JVM one, but Raymond Chen's blog has a couple of good articles that will help you to understand the problem better: [Everybody thinks about garbage collection the wrong way](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/09/10047586.aspx) and [When does an object become available for garbage collection?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/10/10048149.aspx).

Comment: Doing `myClass = null;` does in fact nothing. It only sets the pointer to null, but the Object still exists. UNTIL the Java GC checked that object to see if it is still in use (are there references to it, available from all running threads?). Then GC will delete it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you don't need to call `myClass.clear()`. When there is no way of reaching an object via live references, it will be eligible for garbage collection. That doesn't mean it'll be collected straight away, but it will be *eligible* for collection.

It's *very* rarely appropriate to set references to null for the sake of garbage collection - and it hurts the readability of your code to do so. There are exceptions to this, of course - for example, `ArrayList<T>` will set an element of its internal buffer to `null` when it's no longer needed, in order to avoid accidentally preventing the object from being garbage collected - but usually the fields within an object are valid and useful for as long as the object itself is required. In short, I would almost never even *write* a method like `MyClass.clear()`, let alone call it.

It's rarely worth setting local variables to null either. Your code in `MyMain` isn't clear, because it's not valid outside a method... if you meant *all* of the code to be in a method then you don't need to set `myClass` to be null either. When the method finishes, the variable will no longer contribute as a GC root for the object it was referring to - of course, if *other* GC roots exist, the object still won't be eligible for garbage collection. However, setting a local variable to null at the end of a method is pointless.

Comment: If the java GC works like .net's, then objects are even 'more' eligible for collection than you imply. For example, it's possible for 'this' to be collected during an instance method (as long as it won't be used anymore).

Comment: @Strilanc: While I don't think it's guaranteed, I've not seen that behaviour within any JVM I've used. I think the GCs I've used have even considered all local variables as roots to the end of the method, unlike the .NET GC.

Answer (score 8):

You don't *need* to set *anything* to null in order for it to be GC'd. Don't be paranoid.

Don't try to program Java like C++.

Comment: yep it will be GC'd when it goes out of scope.

Comment: @Byron: No, emphatically *no*. If your comment had been an answer, I'd have downvoted it. For one thing, objects don't go out of scope - variables do. There's a big difference. Secondly, an object may be *eligible* for garbage collection after a particular variable has gone out of scope, but that doesn't mean it will be collected at that point.

Comment: Well, there *are* occasions where it's worth setting a variable to null. For example, imagine if `ArrayList<T>` left references around in its backing array after elements were removed and the remainder shifted down - that would lead to objects being reachable from the GC's point of view even though there would be no way of actually accessing them.

Comment: @Jon: of course, I'm not going to argue with you on that. But, I think the fully-qualified-and-correct answer might be less clear to the OP at this point in learning Java.

Answer (score 7):

"Helping" gc through reference nulling is rarely really needed.

Here is an artificial case where nulling does help:

```
    long[] arr = new long[7000000];
    //arr = null;
    arr = new long[7000000];
```

If you run this with -Xmx100M,it will fail with OutOfMemoryError. If you uncomment the line that makes arr null, it will work fine. This happens because arr reference is still holding the huge array while another one is being created. The memory allocation occurs before the assignment, it triggers a garbage collection, and it fails. When nulling the reference, the GC succeeds making enough space.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need to call `clear` first. The GC will happily find the unused `myObject` reference and reclaim it.

In fact, the GC can handle quite complex object graphs, including circular references:

```
public class Foo
{
    public HashMap a;
    public HashMap b;

    public Foo() {
        a = new HashMap();
        b = new HashMap();
        a.put("b", b);
        b.put("a", a);
    }
}
// ...
public void someFunction() {
   Foo f = new Foo();
}
```

(I wouldn't normally make `a` and `b` public, but I'm trying to be extreme-ish here.)

You don't have to clear `f`, or `a`, or `b`. If nothing is referencing `f`, eventually `f` will be checked for reachability, and the GC won't have an issue with the fact that `a` and `b` mutually reference each other.

Details *(lots and lots of details)* in [the JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're being overly paranoid.  As long as an object is not reachable by running code, it will be collected eventually (though "eventually" may mean "when the program exits", if there's plenty of memory and the GC doesn't need to run).  References within unreachable objects aren't reachable either, so they don't count anymore as far as the GC's concerned.

Note, though, that this means that `finalize` might have already run in your sub-objects, so you can't rely on any sub-stuff that isn't a primitive if you want to do any work in a finalizer.

Comment: Sub-objects may be finalized, but they will certainly not be collected! That would introduce huge vulnerabilities.

Comment: The vulnerabilities already exist. You can't trust anything about some arbitrary object that's been finalized, as the explicit assumption in the finalizer is that unless you make the object "not garbage", the object will never be used again. With that said, the jump from "already finalized" to "already collected" becomes pretty small. In fact, vulnerability-wise, it would be *safer* to discard the object immediately -- the VM would then be explicitly operating on a nonexistent object (which could act like null, or could throw an exception) rather than an existing-but-probably-inconsistent one.

Answer (score 0):

The GC will eventually dispose of the objects correctly.  I think you may be a bit too paranoid.  Although it does not hurt to set the object to null.

And to answer your question if you've called myObject.clear which just does myObject = null then there is no reason to reset it to null again.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to set myclass to null. Once it falls out of scope it is eligible for garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

The GC will dispose of everything that has no reference to it left. So, after `MyClass` is disposed of, there will be no reference left to `myObject` and hence it will be removed by the GC

Answer (score 0):

> *Do I need to call myClass.clear() before setting myClass to null to be sertain the GC will delete myObject inside myClass?*

You don't have to call clear, nor set `myClass` to null.

You cannot be certain it will be collected either, but if the VM needs memory, it will be elegible when `myClass` it self is not referenceable.

So you don't need to worry in this case.